# Can you change templateUrl and controller based on $routeParams?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Is it possible to do something like that

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.when('/:controller/:action',
     {
        templateUrl:$routeParams.controller +'-'+ $routeParams.action + '.html'
        controller: $routeParams.controller+'Ctrl'
     }
  )
})
```

and then if the path is `/Home/index`
      it would grab `Home-index.html` and use `HomeCtrl`,

but for `/Kill/mockingbird` it would use `Kill-mockingbird.html` and `KillCtrl`

Comment: till date dynamic routing is not supported in angular

Comment: but is there any way to get around that? maybe in resolve?

Comment: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2420-Mapping-AngularJS-Routes-Onto-URL-Parameters-And-Client-Side-Events.htm could help for dynamic routes